# Is it possible to keep a webpage active while my computer is turned off or asleep?

Tags: windows, video-streaming, html

My question is pretty simple. As a somewhat new person to the whole coding world, I don't know a whole lot about computers, so I want to ask you guys if it's possible to keep a webpage exchanging data with me while keeping my computer at the minimal energy cost.

The closest thing I can think off is the "Asleep" mode, but that doesn't seem to work for what I need to do. I need a way to have my computer connected to video streams or youtube videos (like if I was watching them) while I sleep or go to school.

It might seem a bit weird the reason as to why I need to be able to do this, but it's basicly for a website that gives you "coins" for every 780 seconds that you watch a stream. Those coins can then be used to enter giveaways of hardware and software (gaming related), the more coins you bet on an item the more chances you have of winning it.

I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your requirement is unclear.. but i suggest use a spare android phone or use a windows phone(convert it to pc using software available online).
Other than that i dont think there are any other option as to keep the website  live and that is simple for you to implement.